# hudson svn publisher plugin not working

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I'm trying to use the [SVN Publisher](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/SVN+Publisher) plugin to commit some artifacts of my build but I'm getting a non-sensical error:

```
workspace: /Users/builder/hudson/workspace/myproject/
Attempting to import to SVN: https://mysvnrepo.com/svn/myproject/_SNAPSHOT_
SVN Publisher: target:  /Users/builder/hudson/workspace/myproject/myproject/_build
SVN Publisher: Error: target Directory not accessable:  /Users/builder/hudson/workspace/myproject/myproject/_build
```

This path is readable by the user that the hudson slave is using.

In looking at the comments on the [SVN Publisher](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/SVN+Publisher) page, it seems that some people have run across this problem while others have not.

My question is: for those of you that have gotten it to work, what did you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the plugin is running *on the hudson server* even though the build is using slaves.  This seems to be a bug in the SVN Publisher plugin. :(

Comment: Do you have any links to a bug report or similar? I have the same problem with an internal problem, and I would like to report the developer to details of a solution.

Comment: Thanks all the same. I ended up asking a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279898/can-hudson-slaves-run-plugins

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to utilize the "Copy files back to the job's workspace on the master node" to get these files back to the server (this part works for me).  It appears to happen after SVN Publisher is run, but that would be OK and simply means that SVN publisher should be committing (or importing) the previous build.  But alas, SVN publisher doesn't seem to be doing anything except logging a message.