# Cannot access file on Jenkins slave with plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slave, jenkins-cli

Through my own plugin, I need to know about the existence of a file in the workspace of a Jenkins slave. But the file can't be found whereas it really exists on the slave

```
artifactsToDeploy = workingDir.act(new FilesDeployerCallable(listener, pairs, artifactoryServer, credentials,
                repositoryKey, propertiesToAdd,
                artifactoryServer.createProxyConfiguration(Jenkins.getInstance().proxy),configurator.getProductKey(),configurator.getArtifactoryKey(), configurator.getBuildType() ,configurator.getRpmParameters(),build,configurator.issendFcmPayload(), configurator.getModule(), configurator.getTaxonomy()));
    }

private static class FilesDeployerCallable implements FilePath.FileCallable<List<Artifact>> {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private final String repositoryKey;
        private BuildListener listener;
        private Multimap<String, String> patternPairs;
        private ArtifactoryServer server;
        private Credentials credentials;
        private ArrayListMultimap<String, String> buildProperties;
        private ProxyConfiguration proxyConfiguration;
        private String artifactKey;
        private String buildType;
        private String module;
        private String taxonomy;
        private RpmParameters rpmParameters;
        private final AbstractBuild build;
        private boolean sendFcmPayload;
        private EnvVars env;

        public FilesDeployerCallable(BuildListener listener, Multimap<String, String> patternPairs,
                                     ArtifactoryServer server, Credentials credentials, String repositoryKey,
                                     ArrayListMultimap<String, String> buildProperties, ProxyConfiguration proxyConfiguration,String productKey,String artifactKey, String buildType, RpmParameters rpmParameters, AbstractBuild build, boolean sendFcmPayload, String module, String taxonomy) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            this.listener = listener;
            this.patternPairs = patternPairs;
            this.server = server;
            this.credentials = credentials;
            this.repositoryKey = repositoryKey;
            this.buildProperties = buildProperties;
            this.proxyConfiguration = proxyConfiguration;
            this.artifactKey = artifactKey;
            this.buildType = buildType;
            this.module = module;
            this.taxonomy = taxonomy;
            this.rpmParameters = rpmParameters;
            this.build = build;
            this.sendFcmPayload = sendFcmPayload;
            this.env = build.getEnvironment(listener);

        }
```

> **java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed:
>   /jenkins/slaveworkspace/workspace/githubMigration at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel@44434cf3:master-replicated:
>   java.io.IOException: Unable to serialize
>   hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper@2ca3869b**    at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:977)    at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:959)    at
>   **dj.pib.productivity.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer.deploy(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:148)**
>     at
>   **dj.pib.productivity.generic.ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator$1.tearDown(ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator.java:352)**
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:171)  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Unable to serialize
>   hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper@2ca3869b  at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.serialize(UserRequest.java:169)   at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.(UserRequest.java:63)   at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:750)    at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:970)    ... 9 more **Caused by:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild**   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
>     at hudson.remoting.UserRequest._serialize(UserRequest.java:158)     at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.serialize(UserRequest.java:167)   ... 12
>   more Collecting metadata...

what am I doing wrong?

Edit 1: Okay, I see the problem is I am passing AbstractBuild build in filesDeployerCallable which is not serializable but I need it for stuff I do. It does give me a warning as to (abstract is raw type and should be parameterized). How Do I parameterize it ? its in the hudson.model.abstractModel

Comment: How many slaves do you have and assuming your plugin operates on the master, how will it know which slave to look at for the file? 

P.S: your constructor args seem to be too many. Can you probably take a look at the builder pattern to create an instance?

Comment: @prabugp - please see edit1

Comment: Can't you run your plugin in the slaves? (check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9281190/2231632 ) If so, you can get all the necessary information from the slave itself. And you'd need to know what type of Build it is. For example `FreeStyleBuild`, of Maven build if you have the plugin and so on. Parameterizing is not a problem but serializing it is.

Comment: @prabugp- I cant run on the slaves as this is a fork of artifactory plugin which doesn't follow the virtual channel route. Anyhow, the build type is always going to be freestyle build. So I need a way to serialize it, I figured if I was able to parameterize it, serializing should just follow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question *How to find out if file exists on a slave*, it should be enough to call `workspace.child("relative/path/to/my.file").exists()` from master. Hiding the difference between local and remote files is the reason `FilePath` exist.

---

There are several way to get around Jenkins model objects not being serializable.

1. Keep the logic on master and send small tasks (`Callable`s) on slave. It is easier to make sure those tasks are simple enough they will never need Jenkins model objects. Using `hudson.Launcher` and `hudson.FilePath` falls into this category.
2. Extract only serializable information before sending `Callable` to slave. For example if all you need is a build number, there is no need to transfer whole build object.
3. Use object [proxies](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/remoting/VirtualChannel.html#export(java.lang.Class,%20T)) so only a remote proxy of a domain object will be present on a slave and all method calls will be dispatched over a channel.