# Publisher plugin is not uploading files

Tags: svn, plugins, jenkins, hudson

I am using Jenkins and SVN Publisher plugin to generate build and then to upload build back to repository.

It generates build but not uploading the build to repository. (I added post build action as to publish to subversion repository)

This is the colsole after generating build.

```
Started by user User2
Building in workspace C:\Users\Prasanth B\.jenkins\jobs\myapp\workspace
Switching from https://myapp.domain.co.in/Source/PushScripts to https://myapp.domain.co.in/Source/PushScripts
Switching to https://myapp.domain.co.in/Source/PushScripts at revision '2013-07-04T12:37:33.002 +0530'
At revision 2591
no revision recorded for https://myapp.domain.co.in/Source/PushScripts in the previous build
workspace: /C:/Users/Prasanth B/.jenkins/jobs/myapp/workspace/
Attempting to import to SVN: http://myapp.domain.co.in/Source/PushScripts/liv/android/Liv/GCM/Logs/
SVN Publisher: target: C:\Users\Prasanth B\.jenkins\jobs\myapp\workspace\pushscripts\liv\android
Finished: SUCCESS
```

My configure page looks like this :

[image]

My question :

1. Why is it not uploading it to repository ? Please guide me.
2. Is there any other plugin available to commit the build files to SVN repository.

Some more details :

```
I am testing the application in windows7 and mac
SVN version : 1.6.16
SVN Publisher plugin version : 0.1
I intalled Jenkins in my PC and I use reverse proxy to access it from other 
computer (I have XAMP installed in my PC)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: got the same issue.. no solution yet.

Comment: @alex you can try bash script to do that, i dont know how exactly to do it, try searching in google

Comment: Are you using `Master Slave` setup? If yes, then you should check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046719/hudson-svn-publisher-plugin-not-working) link.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing your complete setup these two unresolved issues in the "SVN Publisher" plugin could be the problem.

- [Global SVN credentials are not used](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10013)
- [Does not work on remote slaves](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9013)

Unfortunatly the plugin doesn't seem to be maintained anymore.